# How do I run multiple tkinter windows simultaneously in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

so I am making an application that takes notes(similar to Windows Sticky Notes). Since I need to display multiple notes simultaneously, I have used a class which inherits from Thread and also creates a tkinter window. The problem is that my windows do not open simultaneously. The second opens up after the first is closed. Here is the code. What am I doing wrong? Is there another method that I can use? [For now I am just displaying notes I have hard-coded.]

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

class Note(Thread):
nid = 0
title = ""
message = ""

    def __init__(self, nid, title, message):
      Thread.__init__(self)
      self.nid = nid
      self.title = title
      self.message = message


    def display_note_gui(self): 
      '''Tkinter to create a note gui window with parameters '''    
      window = Tk()
      window.title(self.title)
      window.geometry("200x200")
      window.configure(background="#BAD0EF")

      title = Entry(relief=FLAT, bg="#BAD0EF", bd=0)
      title.pack(side=TOP)
      scrollBar = Scrollbar(window, takefocus=0, width=20)
      textArea = Text(window, height=4, width=1000, bg="#BAD0EF", font=("Times", "14"))
      scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
      textArea.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
      scrollBar.config(command=textArea.yview)
      textArea.config(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)
      textArea.insert(END, self.message)
      window.mainloop()

    def run(self):
      self.display_note_gui()

new_note1 = Note(0, "Hello", "Hi, how are you?")
new_note1.start()
new_note1.join()


new_note2 = Note(1, "2", "How's everyone else?")
new_note2.start()
new_note2.join()
```

Comment: use a `Toplevel` Widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of subclassing `Thread` just subclass `Toplevel`, a top level in tkinter is a separate window in the same application which sounds like exactly what you are trying to accomplish:

```
from tkinter import *
#from threading import Thread #no longer needed

class Note(Toplevel):
    nid = 0
    #title = "" #this would block the method to override the current title
    message = ""

    def __init__(self, master, nid, title, message):
      Toplevel.__init__(self,master)
      self.nid = nid 
      self.title(title) #since toplevel widgets define a method called title you can't store it as an attribute
      self.message = message
      self.display_note_gui() #maybe just leave that code part of the __init__?


    def display_note_gui(self): 
      '''Tkinter to create a note gui window with parameters '''    
      #no window, just self
      self.geometry("200x200")
      self.configure(background="#BAD0EF")
      #pass self as the parent to all the child widgets instead of window
      title = Entry(self,relief=FLAT, bg="#BAD0EF", bd=0)
      title.pack(side=TOP)
      scrollBar = Scrollbar(self, takefocus=0, width=20)
      textArea = Text(self, height=4, width=1000, bg="#BAD0EF", font=("Times", "14"))
      scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
      textArea.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
      scrollBar.config(command=textArea.yview)
      textArea.config(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)
      textArea.insert(END, self.message)
      #self.mainloop() #leave this to the root window

    def run(self):
      self.display_note_gui()

root = Tk()
root.withdraw() #hide the root so that only the notes will be visible

new_note1 = Note(root, 0, "Hello", "Hi, how are you?")
#new_note1.start()
#new_note1.join()


new_note2 = Note(root, 1, "2", "How's everyone else?")
#new_note2.start()
#new_note2.join()

root.mainloop() #still call mainloop on the root
```

note that instead of storing the title as an attribute you can call `self.title()` to get the current title of the window and `self.title("new title")` to change it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Thanks for the suggestion about the title, I'm quite new to python and I understood it very well :)

Comment: normally using an attribute called `title` would be fine, it was just the only thing that really needed to change about your code to make it compatible with subclass of `Toplevel`

Comment: if it didn't raise a bunch of `str object is not callable` errors when I was testing it I would have left it exactly how you had it. :)

Comment: I have another question I'm stuck with, could you help me with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504887/how-do-i-unpickle-a-series-of-objects-from-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is multiple note windows then you definitely don't need threads. Tkinter is quite capable of managing dozens or hundreds of open windows.

Just create instances of `Toplevel` for every window except the root window. Here's a somewhat over-engineered example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Notepad(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="word")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", comman=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    Notepad(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    for i in range(5):
        top = tk.Toplevel(root)
        Notepad(top).pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem statement and the Solutions are wonderful for learning. These kinds of examples are needed for Teaching Multithreaded GUI with python's tkinter module.

I faced a similar issue when I created an App with one thread per GUI idea (common idea, I think). BTW, the error is “**RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop**”.

There is another solution I came across using PySimpleGUI package. But that requires a big shift in architecture. I recommend to look at the approach using PySimpleGUI package, It gives some ideas for abstraction on the UI elements.

Comment: You can use `sg.read_all_windows()` to run multiple windows simultaneously.  The error tkinter returns when it detects you're using threads can vary.  It's not always the main loop message.