# How do I unpickle a series of objects from a file in Python?

Tags: python, pickle

I have pickled objects to a file in append mode but it only reads a single object. Here's the code. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
with open('notes.pkl', 'ab') as fileObject:                #append
    pickle.dump(obj, fileObject, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open('notes.pkl', 'rb') as input:                     #read
    obj= pickle.load(input)
    //perform tasks for each obj unpickled from the file
```

Comment: Woah, I must be hallucinating today because I didn't see your code when I first opened this.  Have you tried writing the pickle file as `wb` instead of appending?  Also, what are you pickling?

Comment: you need to call "pickle.load" repeatedly until you hit end-of-file.

Comment: I'm pickling a simple class with three data members. If I use wb it overwrites the previous object, and I need to maintain a series of objects

Comment: thanks @muratgu! Works like a charm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to call `pickle.load` repeatedly until you hit end-of-file.