# Tkinter: 'image ''pyimage2'' doesn't exist'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My full code

```
from tkinter import *
i=0
 for i in range(10) :
 window = Tk()
 window.title('add image')
 window = Canvas(window,width= 600, height= 600)
 window.pack()
 image=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\\Users\\Konstantinos\\New folder\\hello.png")
 window.create_image(0,0, anchor = NW, image=image)
window.mainloop()
```

The error when i run the program

```
File "C:\Programms\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2832, in _create
return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

The error when i debug the program

```
Exception has occurred: TclError
image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
File "C:\Users\Konstantinos\New folder\demo.py", line 9, in <module>
window.create_image(0,0, anchor = NW, image=image)
```

So basically, the program opens an image multiple times. When th program is not in a loop it works but when i put it in a loop it gives me the error. Because i recently started programming i dont really know how to solve the problem and I have looked in other threads with the similar problem but none apply to me. I will appreciate any answer

Comment: Post the code in text inside question, not in a link.  Same for the full error traceback.  BTW, why do you need the for loop?

Comment: I am just guessing here, but are you sure the file exists?

Comment: @LewisMorris  Yes the file exists

Comment: A quick google seems that you can try this `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`

Comment: I tried but it works only for the first window not the rest

Comment: *"So basically, the program opens an image multiple times until the pc crashes."* - Is it the problem or is it what you want? If it is the later, you are trying to create something bad which is not an acceptable question in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from multiple Tk instances. The fix is only having one Tk instance. Since your intention was multiple windows, you can look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36316105/9983213.
A smaller example is:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
for i in range(5):
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Edited code and explanation under for showing images

For each window you create a canvas and assign the image to it. If you are using the same image it isn't necessary to create a new image every loop so we do it once. If you are going to have the image loaded inside a function you most likely need to have `canvas.image = myImage` after `canvas.create_image`. This is because of a bug where images created by PhotoImage can "disappear" when the variable gets out of scope. This is  explained as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27430839/9983213. Also, the canvas part not inside the for-loop is there to also show an image on the `Tk` window and not just the `Toplevel` windows.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
myImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=myImage)
canvas.image = myImage

for i in range(5):
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(top, width=200, height=200)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=myImage)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem _definitely_ comes from multiple Tk instances.

Comment: First, sorry i didnt answered in a while. Second the way i tried doing what you suggested but there is a problem, the image is not shown in all windows.

Comment: If you could find the answer to that I would appreciate it a lot

Comment: I have edited the answer to include code and explanation for also showing images.